# Why aren't smoke simulations showing on my laptop while showing normally on my desktop?

Tags: particles

I am trying to render a smoke simulation on my cpu laptop, but it just won't show even after baking unless I switch the cache to replay (making blender nearly unusable due to lag). When I redo the same process on my GTX 1050 desktop, it shows it like it should. Not only that, the smoke domain with "adaptive domain" checked doesn't move at all on my laptop. [image: This is what it looks like on my laptop]What is the cause of this and how can I bake a smoke simulation normally on my laptop without switching the cache to replay?

Comment: To render the simulation has to be cached. If you cached it to disk on the desktop copy the cache folder from the desktop to the folder file weher you have the project in your laptop. The simulation doesn't have to be re-cached that way.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it